# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to run 'ionic run android -lc' my app stalls for a while and I get a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on my screen.  'ionic run android' and 'ionic serve' run fine.

I found this post and I added `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />` to my config.xml file and my app already has the whitelist plugin.

[net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error in request from cordova app on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037648/neterr-connection-timed-out-error-in-request-from-cordova-app-on-real-device)

I'm still getting the error.  Anyone have any idea the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for someone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303914/ionic-2-error-neterr-connection-timed-out-when-run-on-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Please update your node, phonegap and ionic version.
And it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try one of the following methods:

1. Type `ionic address` to ensure that you are using the correct IP. There should be a list to choose from.
2. Ensure that the android phone is connected to the same WiFi

If error persists, perhaps it is the issue from your computer's antivirus since most of them comes with firewall settings. You might want to disable it and try again. If it works, then the issue is caused by the firewall settings.

Comment: I tried to shut my firewall off but am getting the same problem.  Also ionic address didn't do anything for me.  It just printed a blank line.

Comment: Number 2 was the problem for me, I'm not sure why this answer is downvoted

Comment: thanks, this actually solved my problem. so in my case it is windows firewall that is blocking the connection

Answer (score 0):

If you are running command

```
ionic capacitor run android  -l --external
```

then make sure your device and laptop/pc is on same network.